# Change label of donut chart in c3js

Tags: javascript, jquery, c3.js

I've used setting label on start and its working, here is the working code:

```
var chartDonut1 = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30],
            ['data2', 120],
        ],
        type : 'donut'
    },
    donut: {
        title: "title"
    }
});
```

But, i want to change the label on the donut based on search, and for that purpose i need to use `load` function.

EDIT:
Here is example of donut chart and with title: [LINK](http://c3js.org/samples/chart_donut.html)

How can label be change/set on load?

I've tried setting like code bellow, but i can't make it work:

```
chartDonut1.load({
    json: dataJsonGraph,
    donut: {
        title: 'title1', 
    },
    bindto: '#chartDonut1'                              
});
```

Any suggestion will be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `bindto: '#chartDonut1'` should be declared inside the `generate` function.

It seems you cannot change dynamically graph's title inside load function (In c3js documentation, no reference to it).

You will need to select the chart using d3 instance, then change the title. Example:

```
var label = d3.select('#chart2 text.c3-chart-arcs-title');
label.html(''); // remove existant text 
label.insert('tspan').text('30').attr('dy', 0).attr('x', 0).attr('class','big-font');
label.insert('tspan').text('Test Data').attr('dy', 20).attr('x', 0);
```

A way to change it is to edit html's code : http://plnkr.co/edit/ew5dDA1R3biXnMp80LDd?p=preview

Comment: I've tried this, but still noting... Also i updated the question with example of donut chart, please see it...

Comment: I have edited my answer. In my opinion, it is not possible to change it in `load` function

Comment: If you have more then one chart in same page, this solution will get only and only first chart no matter what type of chart it is.

Comment: If you want to target another chart with id="myChartID", you could use this jquery selector : 
 `var label = d3.select('#myChartID text.c3-chart-arcs-title');` (http://plnkr.co/edit/hwWaMu222yfCtg51Nuuf?p=preview)

Comment: That do the trick! This is the solution for this issue. Thanks.